# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Laravel 8 HELPPPP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, angular, laravel

I'm calling the files as follows

```
<link href="{{asset('assets/css/themes/layout/header/base/light.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/themes/layout/header/menu/light.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/themes/layout/header/menu/light.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/themes/layout/brand/dark.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/themes/layout/aside/dark.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and

```
<script src="{{asset('assets/custom/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/custom/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js')}}"></script>
```

the **app.blade.php** file is on the way: **resources\views\Backend\layout**

I've already used the commands below that solved some files in the folder **auth**

composer require laravel/ui --dev
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm run dev

but it doesn't work to tidy up the files on the other pages, such as **views**, which is where I'm having problems.

does anyone here have the solution???? help me please.

Comment: what do the url's look like in the browser - do they look right?

Comment: yes, example:

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/plugins/custom/gmaps/gmaps.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/pages/widgets.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/custom/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

Move your assets folder into your public folder.